# user warning: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in notifications_event table

Tags: drupal, notifications

I am using Notifications 6.x-2.3 for content subscription and it is working nicely, but when I create more than 4 blogs continuously then I am getting this problem after blog saved :

user warning: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`db_name`.`notifications_event`.`counter` - 88)' query: UPDATE notifications_event SET counter = counter - 88 WHERE eid = 9 in /sites/all/modules/notifications/notifications.cron.inc on line 387

Although mails are sending but some users getting double mail.

I have mentioned this problem in http://drupal.org/node/1561230 but could not get any help.
Any help from here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got resolved this problem by unchecking immediate sending option in notification setting.